# VBA - How to search for folders

Tags: vba, search, for-loop, directory

I have some problems to write a VBA Script (for Outlook) which is searching for folders on a specific drive. The User can give a Harddrive letter ("C", "D",..) and the keyword for the folder (with wildcards) to search for.

Now it searches the drive for folders with the same name. If it found a folder with the same name, it should add the path to a Listbox, and search for more folders with the same name. I have no glue how to do this, I hope you can help me out.

Thank you so much!

Comment: API implementation: [Minimal Code for a Recursive Search for Folders (single drive)](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/fileapi/recursivefolders_minimal.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the Dir()-Function:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Dir-Function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

The linked page contains a sample for looping over all subdirs of a given directory right at the end of it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But it only gives me the names of the current folders under C:\ - but I like to search the whole harddrive, how I can build up the loop for this?